# Xamarin Forms - Custom Listview Cell - UWP Hover Color

Tags: listview, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a basic custom Listview cell in Xamarin Forms like below.

I'm setting the background color and wrapping with a StackLayout Padding to mimic a bottom border.

In UWP, how do I now update the Cell "hover" color so it changes when hovering over the cell?

I can only get it show the light grey hover color when no background is set (default white)

```
<ViewCell.View>

        <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,1" BackgroundColor="#183c57">

          <Grid Padding="8,5" BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column="0"
                         Padding="4"
                         Spacing="2"
                         VerticalOptions="Center">
              <Label Text="{Binding ActivityID}" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"   TextColor="#183c57" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
              <Label Text="{Binding RouteId}" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="#444444" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="#444444" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>

            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Start" Spacing="0" Padding="3" BackgroundColor="{Binding HexColorReadable}"  Margin="0, 4, 10, 0">
              <Label Text="{Binding StatusId}" FontSize="Micro" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#000000"  XAlign="End"  />
            </StackLayout>

          </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
</ViewCell.View>
```

I've tried something like this updating the `App.xaml` of the UWP Project which isn't working.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <Style x:Key="FormsListViewItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter PointerOverForeground="Blue"

                 />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I have test your code, but I did not reproduce your issue. Could I touch your project?

Comment: Nico - are you saying you're able to see the cell highlight on hover? What color?

Comment: The color of the text on the ViewCell turns blue.

Comment: @aherrick Wow, this should be up for the "Question that's most useful for everyone except OP" award (if there is such a thing) :-p. I was trying to figure out how to achieve this, and your question pretty much solved it for me. Now my `ListViewItem` hovering and selection colors are exactly as I need them to be. Thanks!